# Default value for user defined class in C#

Tags: c#, default-value

I see some code will return the default value, so I am wondering for a user defined class, how will the compiler define its default value?

Comment: Just to clarify: all classes (including the ones you create) will default to `null`. Number value types will default to zero and structs are implementation defined (values are set in the constructor).

Comment: Actually, structs have an implicit default constructor that can't be overriden which zero's out the memory used by the struct, so the default value is still compiler defined, not implementation defined.

Comment: Important distinction: _Class members_ are initialized with their default value. Uninitialised local function variables just give compiler errors ;)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

To chime in with the rest, it will be `null`, but I should also add that you can get the default value of any type, using `default`

```
default(MyClass) // null
default(int) // 0
```

It can be especially useful when working with generics; you might want to return `default(T)`, if your return type is `T` and you don't want to assume that it's nullable.

Comment: +1 There is a full explanation of the default keyword at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 22):

The default value for `class` is a `null`

Answer (score 19):

Note: A `DefaultValueAttribute` will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.

You can decorate your properties with the `DefaultValueAttribute`.

```
private bool myVal = false;

[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool MyProperty
{
    get
    {
       return myVal;
    }
    set
    {
       myVal = value;
    }
 }
```

I know this doesn't answer your question, just wanted to add this as relevant information.

For more info see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx

Comment: As the page says, DefaultValue is just something used by the visual designer of VS. It's really completely unrelated to actual initialization; it's just a "hint" of how it should be initialized.

Answer (score 10):

The default value for classes is `null`. For structures, the default value is the same as you get when you instantiate the default parameterless constructor of the structure (which can't be overriden by the way). The same rule is applied recursively to all the fields contained inside the class or structure.

Answer (score 10):

If you are wondering why there isn't a language feature that allows you to  somehow define a non-null default value for a class, remember that a class is a "reference type". A reference type is a reference to allocated memory, or in other words, anything except null is a constructed instance of that object which required memory to be allocated. So now thinking about how to integrate the "default" keyword into .NET so that it works for classes, imagine two implementations that could be considered:

1. You can define a static instance that is marked as the default. Maybe "default" becomes like an access modifier (e.g. public default readonly etc). This could work, maybe. But is it really a worthy language feature? At least this way every "default" would point to the same static instance of memory.
2. What if the default constructor were called every time you used the default keyword on a class? This would be terrible because two default values could possibly be unequal to each other if you didn't override Equals to not compare references, and also terrible because of the memory management and memory allocation performance hit, and side affects from the constructor.

So in summary I think it is a language feature that we really don't want. And default(MyClass) will always == null.

Comment: Great explanation. I sort of got the impression that `default` was just meant to be an alternative to `null` when the IDE suggested to replace `null` for a generic `<T>` with `default(T)` instead.

Answer (score 10):

I would make this "default" class instance a field rather than property, like how `System.String.Empty` looks:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public static readonly Person Default = new Person() 
    {
        Name = "Some Name",
        Address = "Some Address"
    };
}

...

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string address = String.Empty;

    Person person = Person.Default;

    //the rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If it is a reference type, the default value will be `null`, if it is a value type, then it depends.

Answer (score 4):

```
Assert.IsTrue(default(MyClass) == null);
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this assert?

Answer (score 2):

For reference types or nullable value types the default will be `null`:

```
Person person = default; // = null
IEnumerable<Person> people = default; // = null
int? value = default; // = null
```

For value types, it depends on which value type it is:

```
int value = default; // = 0
DateTime dateTime = default; // = 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
Guid id = default; // = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving some other ppl's time, hopefully.

Obvious option nowadays (for which I still had to google a bit, as landed on this topic first) is to write an extention, that helps you to initialize a class, regardless of it's own complications (like constructor getters/setters, which prevent simple default value direct assignition).

Modifying previous answer a bit:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public static readonly Person Default = new Person() 
    {
        Name = "Some Name",
        Address = "Some Address"
    };
}
```

=>

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
public static class PersonExtentions
{
    public static Person withDefaults(this Person obj) {
      obj.Name = "John Doe";
      return obj;
    }
}
```

And then

```
Person x = new Person.withDefaults();
```